# Having trouble with Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, popper.js

For some reason, my dropdown menu doesn't function in bootstrap4. I have jquery, bootstrap, and I'm not totally sure if popper was properly imported. Was wondering if anyone could point me as to if I did something wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning BootStrap</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"  ></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"> </script>



</head>

<body>


<p class="lead text-center">This is my website.</p>
<div class="dropdown">

<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button/>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">

        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">first link</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">second link</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">third link</a>


</div>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your script before ending body tag.

Comment: And put popper before bootstrap.

Comment: still wont work.

Comment: Check path is correct or not...

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of your bootstrap and popper.js script tags, so bootstrap is the very last to load.

1. jquery
2. popper.js
3. bootstrap

Comment: Double check your script files. Are they accessible / loaded correctly? You can try to use cdn instead of local ones for bootstrap and jquery as well to check if they're the problem.

Comment: Orient yourself on bootstraps introduction example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: so if i have my popper.min.js in a folder called js i should refer to it as <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Comment: In theory, yes. Note: the folder *js* should be in the same folder as your html file.

Answer (score 0):

The version you have downloaded is probably a minified version. I am saying this because it is referring something like `js/bootstrap.min.js`.

You have to include `jquery` and `popper` with the help of `stackpath link` they are not available in `bootstrap` Downloaded version. below is the code that you should be using in order to make that dropdown workable!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Learning BootStrap</title>



<!-- ----------------------------Link you have to include before your css and js file -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>



  <!-- ----------------------------Your File --> 

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


  <p class="lead text-center">This is my website.</p>
  <div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">

      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">first link</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">second link</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">third link</a>


    </div>
  </div>





</body>


</html>
```